# count lines together with summing a specific column

Tags: awk

I would very much appreciate if someone can help this task. I am hoping to do this with awk, but if there is better strategy other than awk, I would also like to know.

This is infile,

```
S,0,3118,*,0,*,*,*,10-2,c645,5
H,0,648,99.2,+,0,0,250I648M2220I,10-2,c4204,1
H,0,597,99.2,+,0,0,314I597M2207I,10-2,c4022,1 
S,1,2488,*,0,*,*,*,10-2,c17,4
H,1,798,97.4,+,0,0,1407I798M283I,10-2,c232,2
H,1,796,98,+,0,0,628I796M1064I,10-2,c67,1
H,1,751,97.5,-,0,0,668I144M3D290MD313M1073I,10-2,c115,1
H,1,792,98.4,+,0,0,628I792M1068I,10-2,c380,1
S,2,2437,*,0,*,*,*,10-2,c102,7
S,3,2218,*,0,*,*,*,10-2,c1081,10
H,3,928,99.2,-,0,0,3D925M1293I,10-2,c986,3
```

the outfile what I would like to have is,

outfile

```
0,3,7
1,5,9
2,1,7
3,2,13
```

So, if the second column of infile is same, count the number of lines (second column of the outfile) together summing value of the last column (third column of the outfile).

I tried as

```
awk -F',' '{a[$2] += $11}; END{for(c in a) print c, a[c]}' < infile
```

but I do not know how to count the line number together.

Comment: I have tried this, but I do not know how to count the line number together. 
 awk -F',' '{a[$2] += $11}; END{for(c in a) print c, a[c]}' < infile

Comment: Your idea was right, you just needed to use two arrays

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer accepted with a vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple `Awk` command, with logic to hash on the `$2` value. Once to track the count of occurrences of the second column value and once for the sum on the last field. It goes like

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{unique[$2]++; uniqueSum[$2]+=$NF}END{for (i in unique) print i,unique[i],uniqueSum[i]}' file
```

which will get you the output you need. The part `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` takes care of setting the input and output field separators to `,` and `{unique[$2]++; uniqueSum[$2]+=$NF}` is for hashing the count of the unique ID value from `$2` and its summed up value in last column. the `END` clause is run after all the lines are processed. So we print the unique column, its count and its total sum to get the output as you need.

```
0,3,7
1,5,9
2,1,7
3,2,13
```

Comment: Thank you Inian! I could perform the task with your command. And sorry to vote!